# Installing .air without admin rights any other idea?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex3

I tried the following technique to build an update mechanism for my .air: http://www.mabulous.net/air-applications-that-can-be-updated-without-requiring-admin-rights

It does something but I can't get the right sizes. I am not really familiar with ActionScript projects and launching an app with a sprite. I just can't get the launched app to have a 100% width and height. It gets a huge white border and a total wrong resolution it even looks like it has been scaled. Did anyone run into the same problem?

What if I would install the .air on the desktop and overwrite the META-INF, assets and swf with the new update (unpacking it). Would that not be a way of updating my application.

Comment: did you set the stagescalemode?

Comment: stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN; It looks like it is a stage problem. Now the left border is fixed but the stage width continues to be 500 and the height 375. I don't get it why these values? If i set the stage height my stage width automatically changes to 500 and if I change my stage width my stage height changes to 375 automatic.

Comment: Boom! I had to set stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
   stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
   stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN; Now it looks like it works. Thanks Marijn and thanks article http://www.mabulous.net/air-applications-that-can-be-updated-without-requiring-admin-rights